# iPhone:How many days Apple reviews an application?

Tags: iphone

I submitted my iPhone application in Apple Store through online. It is in Review status. I just want to know how many days generally Apple will take to review an application?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally about two weeks.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to give a precise time.  I have had apps take anywhere from 3 days to 6 months.  Apple does claim to do something like 90% in under 2 weeks though.

Answer (score 1):

The current velocity seems to be about 2 weeks.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has a 'App Store Review Status' [widget](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/news/) on their website. No clue how accurate it is.

Answer (score 0):

Last app I submitted took them about 22 days to get back to me, resubmitted a binary and t only took about 8 or 9 days. It really just depends on the volume they have right now and what arbiterary rules they decide to pull out on you (see google voice app)